# how can i get the picture in form2 to object of GunaImageButton in form1?(C#-Windows form application)

Tags: c#, winforms

```
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        GunaImageButton imageButton;
        private void gunaButton4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //object of image button 
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                imageButton= new GunaImageButton();
                flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(imageButton);
                imageButton.BackColor = Color.Navy;
                imageButton.Width = 262;
                imageButton.Height=159;
                imageButton.BackgroundImage = this.f2.picturebox1.BackgroundImage;//the problem in this line
                //System.NullableReferenceException:Object reference not set to an instance //of an object.
                imageButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Btn_Click);

            }

        }
```

I need to get pic in form2 to form1

Comment: Please edit the question and format the code, also add some description about the problem which you are trying to solve, the expected behavior, the issue you have encountered, any exception details, etc. Also read [ASK].

Comment: please use the [C#] tag, if your question is not specific to the 2 ancient versions that you tagged.